# How many customers per day would a medieval-era tavern serve on average in a big city?

Tags: economy, medieval, urban-fantasy

Additionally, how many meals and/or drinks would they serve per day on average?

Comment: How big is the tavern?  A bar with a small kitchen and two tables is going to have fewer patrons than a large tavern.

Comment: There are a lot, *a lot* of assumptions to get close to an answer. Care to narrow this down?

Comment: Also, when in the "medieval era"? That's a period of nearly a thousand years, from the late 400s to the mid-1400s CE.  At the beginning of that period, the closest thing to a tavern would either be a lodging house or a small building attached to a brewery.  By the end, you had public houses.

Comment: Also, are you looking for an answer with sources? It can help narrow the field a bit, too

Comment: @PipperChip Well *now* I'm interested. I wonder what kinds of records exist? Might be interesting just to see an answer of sample taverns for which bookkeeping records have managed to survive.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Prior to the Black Death in England, for instance, any peasant woman would be an alewife when she made a batch of ale.  She would make more than she needed and sell the rest *ad hoc*.  Taverns chiefly stemmed from the increase of wages in the immediate wake of the Black Death.

Comment: Hello @CameronCrane, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. This question is too vague. "Medieval" is a word that refers to a +/- 1,000 year era starting around 476ce. That's a VERY long time during which European population nearly tripled despite the Plague. The average size of a large city in 476 was much different than the avg size in 1450. The tavern statistics in England would be different from those in France, Germany, or the Middle East ("medieval" doesn't just refer to Europe). We need some specifics because "average" is almost meaningless.

Comment: @Mary: Beer, even if called ale, is a disgusting thin yellow beverage drunk by Germanic barbarians. Civilized peoples drink wine, and wine has been drunk in taverns for thousands of years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Western and central Europe only, middle to late middle ages only. That is still half a millennium and a lot of different places, so the answer is generic.

There were small taverns, there were large taverns, there were small inns, there were large inns. Some had a few dozen customers per day, some had hundreds.

[image: Revelry at an inn by Jan Steen]

<sup>[*Reverly at an inn*](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Jan_Steen_-_Revelry_at_an_Inn_-_WGA21761.jpg) by Jan Steen, second half of the 17th century. Post-medieval, and set in the great hall of an inn instead of a tavern, but close enough.</sup>

In the western world, taverns and inns would sell *a lot* of [ale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ale) (= sort of beer) and wine; even a not-very-large tavern would expect to sell tens of gallons (at least a hundred liters) of ale or wine per day; a large tavern could go through several barrels of ale or wine in a day. Medieval taverns did not sell wine by the "drink", by rather by the jug, which would be one or two liters in modern units; beer was sold by the [tankard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tankard), between half a liter (one pint) and a liter (two pints).

Note that in wine-producing countries beer was not drunk during the Middle Ages; on the other hand, wine *was* imported in large quantities in England and other such not-wine-producing lands.

It is hard to get a correct idea of the prices, because most prices were in silver, and the price of silver crashed after the discovery of the New World. (The western and central European Christian nations did not have any functional gold currency in the Middle Ages; only the shrinking Roman Empire and the Islamic world did.) To form an idea, a gallon (4 liters) of wine could be about 4 to 6 grams of silver (1/8 to 1/5 oz), which would be about 3 to 4 dollars or euros in 2023 money; beer was less than half that, but beer was not popular *at all* in places where wine grapes grow. (Keep in mind that silver was much more valuable in the Middle Ages, so a better approximation would be maybe 9 to 12 dollars.)

While taverns *did* sell food, it was not their main business. (But remember that beer *was* food in the Middle Agesl; a person could drink a gallon, or 4 liters, of ale per day.) The food sold at taverns was mostly bread and cheese, with the occasional roasted meat. People who did not eat at home bought food from street vendors. *Inns* did sell food as a main business, mostly for the people lodged there.

In the Islamic world inns did not sell alcoholic beverages. I don't even think they had taverns comparable to the western world; they did have inns, and the inns did sell food.

- Kenneth Hodges's [Medieval price list](http://medieval.ucdavis.edu/120D/Money.html).
- [Medieval prices and wages](https://blog.datawrapper.de/medieval-prices-wages/) at Datawrapper.
- [Prices and costs in Anglo-Saxon England and the Viking Age](https://regia.org/research/misc/costs.htm) at Regia Anglorum.
- [Medieval inns and taverns](https://www.lostkingdom.net/medieval-inn-tavern/) at the Lost Kingdom.
- And, of course, Ian Mortimer's [*The Time Traveler's Guide to Medieval England: A Handbook for Visitors to the Fourteenth Century*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1439112908); the link goes to Amazon. A brief extract with a [list of prices](https://www.historyextra.com/period/medieval/a-time-travellers-guide-to-medieval-shopping/) is availalble at Historia Extra.